# How do I install a fan rated junction box and replace the existing one?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a fan I was trying to install but when I removed the cover that was covering the junction box I realized it felt kind of flimsy, I proceed to unscrew the blue plastic box from the mounting points and see it is held on by a rather thin hangar and realize from looking at the spec sheet it is not fan rated.

Question: What is the best way to make this fan rated?
I am willing to go in the attic if I need to but the ceilings are vaulted so it is kind of cramped in there.
Is there a solution where I can just slip it in through the existing hole?
what kind of hanger/box do I need?

The current box, its the second one: https://www.mainelectricsupply.com/customer/docs/skudocs/ctxez20chg-spec-sheet.pdf

The fans I need to install are not small and light but not heavy. Another thing to note is that there is fiberglass insulation directly over this spot and presumably the others, when I removed the box I had to touch some of it to get it back on the hangar

Comment: Interestingly the first and third boxes in your posted spec sheet show" not suitable for fan installation" under the spec. However the second , which is the one you say you have, does not have that disclaimer.  Perhaps you do have a fan rated box.

Comment: I thought that might be the case but I took the disclaimer to be for all of them since it felt very flimsy.

Comment: The boxes shown by the OP would require getting into the attic to install. Those are meant for new construction or when there is attic access. Also they might be for light fixtures only and not fan rated. If what you have is the first one nailed to the side of the joist, it is possible that you could just keep it in place if your fan has hardware to shift to the joist. I have installed new Hunter fans that way. What brand of fan do you have?

Comment: OP stated that the original box was the 2nd on the list.  That one does NOT have the disclaimer making it non suitable for fan installation.

Comment: How did this work out? I have another idea on how to get the brace out if you are interested.

Comment: It ended up not working out yet, upon finding the box location in the attic it was completely unreachable due to being vaulted ceilings. I was able to remove one which was not in too deep and it was in fact screwed in to the joist so I have to figure out a way to remove the other ones that I’ll have to do through the hole. Oddly enough the other harder ones have joist in a perfect location to side mount a box but for some reason they chose to use hangers anyways but that still leaves me with how to get the old hardware out. What’s the idea?

Comment: You say the box is attached to a brace and is  located right next to a joist? In  removing the box from the brace, did you damage the box or the brace? Could that box be reattached to the brace? I ask because some fans (e.g., Hunter) have hardware that allows using the original box if it is attached to the side of the joist and MIGHT work on your box if it is right next to the joist. In this installation the fan is shifted maybe 2 inches and is hung from below the joist not below the box. The fan shroud is large enough to cover the box. What is the mfgr of your fan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your favorite DIY/home improvement store and purchase an "old work" fan box with mounting bracket.

These are designed to fit into the ceiling through the existing hole in the ceiling (therefore not requiring any attic access). They have a rod & braces that will extend to brace the bar against the joists to the side and have a strong box that will support your fan.

Of course, if you *do* have attic access, then you can get a regular fan-rated box and attach it to a 2x4 or 2x6 nailed into the ceiling joists on either side. TBH, the "old work" box is actually an easier install in probably 90% of the cases...

Comment: would something like this work? to my understanding I could just twist it until it is tight but would those little bits that poke into the wood really hold a fan? another thing that occurred is that if the current mounting is nailed in I might have to go up in the attic anyways
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-15-3-cu-in-Remodel-Construction-Ceiling-Fan-Brace-with-1-1-2-in-Box-CMB150-OB/205383178

Comment: I purchased mine at Lowes, but it is quite similar. The legs sit on the drywall (in my case on the plaster & lath) of the ceiling while the barbs on the ends dig into the joists. All in all, yup, that's _exactly_ what these are designed to do!

Comment: What make and model of fan are you installing? Have you already purchased it? Some fans are designed to use a non-fan rated box if the box is nailed to the side of a wooden joist. Fans with that design are designed so that the fan bracket is installed off center of the box, supported by two special screws that screw into the edge of the joist. The fan shroud is large enough so that it covers the electrical box. Of course this means that the new fan would be displaced by 2 or 3 inches from where the center of the old fixture was. Often this is not observable, but sometimes it would be.

Comment: In the case above the existing electrical box is left in place, but does not bear the weight of the fan. I have installed new Hunter fans that way. The special wood screws come with the fan hardware. On the other hand some boxes supporting light fixtures have light metal braces to locate the fixture between two ceiling joists. In that case you would need to remove the light bracing and the original electrical box and replace it with an expandable fan rated brace which will fit the joist spacing of 16" to 24" on center. Putting the new brace in place can be done from below inside the house . .

Comment: . . . getting the old light weight bracing out might be a challenge for an inexperienced installer. Installing one of these fans is a challenge if you have never done it before, but can be done if you understand the instructions, have reasonable hand and arm strength,  and enough patience to work through it slowly.

Comment: it appears the old box hangar is held in with nails and won't come out, attic is the only way thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: Is the the current brace nailed to the sides of the joists that face the hole? If so,you may be able to cut the brace in the hole then work the braces back and forth and up and down to loosen the nails. Then you could reach in with a prybar between the brace and the joist and finish getting the brace out.

Comment: If you can cut/bash the old box apart/up, you should be able to use a saw to cut the bar, if it doesn't come loose on its own after bashing the box.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the new fan rated bar and box is the best way to proceed.

To totally remove the old light-weight brace would probably require going into the attic, but you should be able to just cut the old brace in the middle and bend both ends up (and perhaps laterally) out of the way of the new fan brace. Before cutting the old bar remove the electrical box. A sawsall would be best but you could use a hacksaw.

The original brace might be fastened on the back and top sides of the joists. The new fan rated one fits inside and is tightened so that it digs into the inside faces of the joists.

If however the original brace is nailed to the insides of the joists you might have to remove it entirely. I woud cut it in the center, push the ends up and reach in with a small prybar to pull out the nails and free the ends. Or you could do this from the attic.

The new fan rated bar is inserted without the box attached and once the bar is tightened then the box is attched to the bar. I have two Hunters installed this way and they are very secure.

Comment: How did this work out?